# Overlays not displaying in android maps

Tags: android, dictionary, overlay, point, geo

So I'm just trying to create a generic mapView in android and put a few geopoints in it. I've followed the instructions from the android developer website and had no success... can anyone help? here is my code.

```
public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    Context mContext;

    public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        // defines the bounds for the overlayItems
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        // returns the correct ArrayList position from int i
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // returns number of items in ArrayList
        return mOverlays.size();
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
        dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
        dialog.show();
        return true;
    }

}
```

//Here's my main class

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maptastic);
        ((TextView)((FrameLayout)((LinearLayout)((ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView()).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        setTitle("Field Trip");

        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.supaaaa);
        HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
        //initControls();

        MapView mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mcontroller = mapview.getController();
        // Plot all geo points
        for (Entry<Integer, FieldTripStop> cur : Statics.fieldTripStops.entrySet())
        {
            // get the FieldTripStop object from the current hash table entry
            Statics.currentFTStop = cur.getValue();
            // concatenate numbers before (all) and after (6) the decimal, since
            // geopoints only accept 6 numbers past the decimal.
            theLat = Statics.currentFTStop.latitude;
            theLong = Statics.currentFTStop.longitude;

            /*
             * String manipulation method
             * 
             * theLat = theLat.replace(".","");
             * theLat = theLat.substring(0, 8);
             * theLong = theLong.replace(".","");
             * theLong = theLong.substring(0, 8);
             * point = new GeoPoint((int)(Integer.valueOf(theLat)), (int)(Integer.valueOf(theLong))); 
             */

            theDLat = Double.parseDouble(theLat);
            theDLong = Double.parseDouble(theLong);



            //olay = new OverlayItem(point, "herp", "derp");
            //olayitems.add(olay);
            List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapview.getOverlays();





            point = new GeoPoint((int)(theDLat*1E6), (int)(theDLong*1E6));
            OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "holda, Mundo!", "I'm in Mexico City~!");

            itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

        }
```

Comment: FWIW, here is a somewhat simpler example: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk

Comment: In my emulator the map displays as a grid. I think this is a google map Api problem but I don't know how to fix it. I just got a fresh api key from google.

Comment: Did you put your api key into the manifest?

Comment: ....you have to put in your manifest..?

Comment: actually, I think I might have figured it out with a combined help from you and commons :D Thank ya!

Comment: No, I was mistaken ... the api key goes into the layout resource, not the manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You need to a) use only a single `HelloItemizedOverlay` (instead one for each point) and b) add this overlay to the map *before* you add the markers (In your current code, the overlay is not yet associated with the map when `populate` is called, so the map does not receive any notification and doesn't refresh itself).</strike>

Some things to check:

- Did you specify your api key for the MapView? *

*) How to specify your api key (in the layout resource for your activity):

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/map"
    ...
    android:apiKey="your-api-key-here"/>
```

Comment: You can call `populate()` before adding the map to the `MapView` without problems.

Comment: Does it refresh once the overlay is added to the map?

Comment: I've updated my question with my current code because it still isn't showing the geopoint in my emulator :'(.. I've never done maps in android before so I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Do I need my drawable to be certain dimensions or..?

Comment: Apparently, yes. The example I have been showing for years calls `populate()` in the overlay's constructor, without any problems.

Comment: Nothing glaring jumps out, except for the use of multiple overlays instead of one -- and the timing of when the layer is added to the map (which CommonsWare says is irrelevant)

Comment: I just fixed what you said was wrong @Tony. I put the itemizedOverlay outside the loop so it only creates one. no success :'(